# GroupBy - Project result to a list<T>

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a XML file :

```
<Cars>
    <Element name="A">
        <Car Color="Blue" Id="1"/>
    </Element>
    <Element name="B">
        <Car Color="Green" Id="2"/>
           <Car Color="Yellow" Id="3"/>
    </Element>
</Cars>
```

And one class :

```
public class Car
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

I want to group by `name` and for each result I want to have a list of `Car`s

I've tried :

```
Doc.Root.Elements("Element")
        .GroupBy(x => x.Attribute("name").Value).ToList();
```

But how to convert the result of each group to List of `Car` ?

Comment: I think your main problem is that your XML is not valid

Comment: do you have two cars in Element B?

Comment: Yes @AdilMammadov My second group must have two list for result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("your file");
var result = doc.Root.DescendantsAndSelf("Element")
                     .Select(element => new 
                         { 
                             Element = element.Attribute("name").Value, 
                             Cars = element.Descendants("Car")
                                           .Select(car => new Car 
                                           { 
                                               Id = car.Attribute("Id").Value, 
                                               Color = car.Attribute("Color").Value 
                                           }).ToList() 
                     }).ToList();
```

If you have in your document a few time something like `<Element name="A">` with it's items then you can add before the last `ToList()`:

```
.GroupBy(element => element.Element, 
         (key, group) => new 
             { 
                 Element = key, 
                 Cars = group.SelectMany(item => item.Cars).ToList() 
             })
```